# Reversing rand in perl 5.10.0, anyone know where to find the source code for rand/srand?

Tags: perl, random, crypt, srand

I am doing an assignment where I have a passwd file and I am to find all the passwords in it. Most of them were easy with Jack the ripper and some tweaking but the extra credit requires I find a 8 byte Alphanumeric password generated by rand in perl 5.10.0 and encrypted with crypt.
I came up with three ways to approaching this:

1. **Brute force**: 62^8 Computations = 300 Weeks on my machine. I could
   rent a server with 300 times my machine power to do in 1 week.
   Somehow that feels like a waste of resources/electricity for an
   extra credit.
2. **Break Crypt**: Not sure on this one, I have however generated a
   char-set from the other passwords I found, reducing the Incremental
   brute force to 5 days, but I think that will only work if this
   password contains only characters present in the previous ones (17
   plain-texts), so maybe if i get lucky! (Highly Unlikely)
3. **Break rand**: If I can find the same seed used to generate the
   password. I can then generate dictionaries to feed to Jack. In order
   to get the seed from the file given to me however I have to
   understand how perl is creating the seed (and if it is even possible
   on 5.10.0).

From what I have researched on earlier Perl versions only the System Time was used as a seed. I made a script that uses the `m_time` (Time From Epoch) on the passwd file given to me (+-10 to be sure although I'm sure the file got generated in one second) as seed to generate a dictionary, in this format, since I do not know at what call of `rand()` my password actually starts:

> abcdefgh
>  bcdefghi
>  cdefhijk

I fed the dictionary to Jack. Of course this didn't work because after Perl 5.004 Perl uses other stuff (the point of my question) to generate a seed.

So, my question is if anyone knows where to find the source code Perl uses to generate the seed, and/or source code for rand/srand. I was looking for something that looked like this, but for version 5.10.0:

[What are the weaknesses of Perl's srand() default seed, post version 5.004?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497045/what-are-the-weaknesses-of-perls-srand-default-seed-post-version-5-004)

I tried using grep in the `/lib/perl` directory but I get lost in all the `#define` structure files.

Also feel free to let me know if you think I am completely offtrack with the assignment and/or any advice on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to look in /lib/perl, you want to look in the Perl source.

Here is [Perl_seed() in util.c as of v5.10.0](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/aa00ea78eea85d7a3ca094d43e18e9c8c4da2ebb/util.c#L5192-L5272), which is the function called if `srand` is called without an argument, or if `rand` is called without `srand` being called first.

As you can see, on a Unix system with random device support, it uses bytes from `/dev/urandom` to seed the RNG. On a system without such support, it uses a combination of the time (with microsecond resolution if possible), the PID of the Perl process, and memory locations of various data structures in the Perl interpreter.

In the `urandom` case, guessing the seed is effectively impossible. In the second case, it's still of difficulty probably similar to brute-forcing the passwords; you have 20 bits of unpredictability from the microsecond timestamp, up to 16 bits from the PID, and an unknown amount from the memory addresses, probably between 0 and 20 bits if you know details of the system where it was run, but up to 64 or 96 bits if you have no knowledge at all.

I would say that attacking Perl's `rand` by guessing the seed is probably not practical, and reversing it from its output is probably not either, especially if it was run on a system with `drand48`. Have you considered a GPU-based brute-forcing tool?

Comment: but if the password was generated on windows, where (until more recent perls) you only have 15 bits of random value (and no extra seed, afaik), it's another story

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses. I will play with the information for the next few days before I mark as answered. I haven't tried GPU-based yet as well so I will look into it. I was concentrating on the srand/rand side because of hints from people who done this before, however it seems to me that unless he used "use 5.004;" then there is no adequate (easy) way of breaking rand.

Comment: Well after spending a week on it I finally I understand how perl rand works.<br>

1) At the first rand of perl it will call srand(), it uses an integer value as a seed (2^32) possibilities, but the REAL seed has 2 trailing bytes unused.

2) Each rand will actually use the UNIX drand48() and change the seed following the documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry for failing posting replies, having a hard time formatting in a response. 
This link explains drand48 on Unix system :
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html
The real seed has always 6 bytes. Thanks a lot hobbs for putting me in the right direction.